# Multiple Proxy in Gradle

Tags: github, proxy, gradle

Currently I am developing a small POC. The project is in Github. I want to simultaneously work from my home PC and Office PC. My office network runs behind a proxy. I have mentioned the proxy configuration in gradle.properties file.

Now while running it from my home PC gradle failed to download some dependencies due to proxy. My home PC doesn't have any proxy configuration.

I have a workaround of this issue by commenting out the proxy configuration in the properties file. **But is there any permanent solutions so that My Application will automatically detect  and choose the corresponding proxy settings.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are different machines, you can declare the proxy settings in the per-user properties file (`USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`). If it's the same machine, you can use a tool that switches out `USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` depending on your current location.